# local image is showing blank in expo go, but its available in the inspector

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image, expo

I am working on a react native app project using expo. Large size images are not showing but low sizes are. Yet the inspector identifies that an image is available in the application.

I've tried using low size images in kb and they are working fine but images up up to 1mb aren't showing though they are available in the expo go inspector.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ImageBackground, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
   

    <View style={styles.container}>

      <StatusBar style='light' />
      <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/images/lll.jpg')} resizeMode='cover' style={styles.background}>


      <SafeAreaView style={styles.normal}>
        <View style={styles.normalView}>
            <Text>The light of the world</Text>

            {/* This image isn't showing */}
            <Image source={require('./assets/images/kkk.jpg')} resizeMode='contain' style={{width: 50, height: 50, borderColor: 'black', }} />
        </View>

      </SafeAreaView>
      

  
     </ImageBackground>
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  background: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  normal: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  normalView: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginTop: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 30,
  }
});
```